# R and Shiny: Dynamic UI based on data from server module

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a Shiny app with its UI elements depending on the number of observations. The app plots as many plots in UI module as many observations are calculated in server module. My code below is just an example of what I need:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(corrplot)

employee <- c('John Doe', 'John Doe', 'John Doe',
              'Peter Gynn', 'Peter Gynn', 'Peter Gynn',
              'Jolie Hope', 'Jolie Hope', 'Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800,
            22000, 25000, 24000,
            23000, 25500, 24500)
year <- c("2016", "2015", "2014",
          "2016", "2015", "2014",
          "2016", "2015", "2014")
mydata<-data.frame(employee, salary, year)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "test", titleWidth=600) 
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable=TRUE)

frowlist<-list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(mydata$employee))){
    frowlist[[i]]<-assign(paste0("frow",i),fluidRow( 
    status="success",
    collapsible = TRUE, 
    mainPanel(do.call(plotOutput,"myoutput"), width='98%')
    ))
}

body <- do.call(dashboardBody, frowlist) # Binding rows to body of dashboard
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin="yellow") 

server <- function(input, output) {
    myoutput<-reactive({
        myoutput<-list()
    for (i in 1:length(unique(mydata$employee))){
        myoutput[[i]]<-assign(paste0("output$plot_",i),renderPlot({ 
            ggplot(mydata[which(mydata$employee==unique(mydata$employee)[i])]$employee, aes(x = year, y = salary)) + geom_bar()
        }))
    }
    myoutput
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The error that keeps appearing is

```
Error : second argument must be a list
```

How can I pass the list from UI module as variable of a function?

**EDIT**
What I can't achieve first of all is reading the *myoutput* variable from the server side of the script as a list in the global-like side of the script.

Comment: Please indicate the type of shiny plot you expect? Please review simple shiny tutorials using shiny dashboard before debugging this complicated example: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/get_started.html

Comment: It is not so much the type of plots as the number of plots I expect. I expect N plots where N=number of observations in mydata dataframe. Hence, in my example, there should be three barplots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround to this, based on Winston Chang's work https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/

```
max_plots <- 5

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
      plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
    })

    # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
    # to display properly.
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })

  # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
  # are visible on the web page.
  for (i in 1:max_plots) {
    # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
    # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
    # of when the expression is evaluated.
    local({
      my_i <- i
      plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")

      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        plot(1:my_i, 1:my_i,
             xlim = c(1, max_plots),
             ylim = c(1, max_plots),
             main = paste("1:", my_i, ".  n is ", input$n, sep = "")
        )
      })
    })
  }
})
```